# 3 way switch to 4 lights rewiring to 15 LEDs

Tags: electrical, switch, led

[image: existing] 
[image: new LEDs]Have a basement with 4 beams that had 2 lights in bay 2 and 2 lights in bay 4.
Dropping ceiling and want 3 LED lights in each bay.
Can I run 3 new 12/2 wires to bays 1,3,5 which will be spliced to the old 12/2 rerouted from bay 2 and new wire ran to bay 2 in a new junction box?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. It's difficult to know what you mean; would you add a diagram to your question?

Comment: What makes you believe you *can't*?

Comment: Well the diagram now looks like you want to do more than add a light to each of those bays. What is it that you are really trying to do?

Comment: those are 2 different diagrams, bottom is existing, top is the way I want to do it

Comment: Your top drawing does not make sense - do you want the lights to operate like a regular 3-way switch wiring would operate? If so the top drawing does not look like it will do that.With the J-Box you only need to supply voltage from switch to j-box as if it is 1 light and the j-box feeds power to the Lights - see normal 3-Way switch and make like J-box is your light. What LED's are you using BR30 Recessed Light equivs, or something else ? Post a link to it or a picture of it - make/model is helpful if you don't use a link.

Comment: Yes, what is going on with the switch boxes?

Comment: That bottom drawing shows a cable loop.  That is bad.  Cable diagrams should look like a tree, and shouldn't contain any loops or enclosed areas.  If it wasn't for the beams, if you draw it so no cables cross, you should be able to use the paint bucket tool in any open space and have it fill the whole page.

Comment: Harper, that is the way it was wired. the bottom light wire must go up to the attic and back down to get over an air duct. the top light would not work without that cable loop, still need to get to top switch, was just trying to avoid opening that up. That has to be where the power comes in.

Comment: If you think you may not want to have all the lights on at the same time (say, to keep glare off a TV) you'll want to get fixtures that are programmable or can take a smart bulb.  I have a room with 12 lights on the same switches, but I can turn on/off whatever bulbs I want with an app.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some samples for how a 3-Way switch is wired.

Depending on how your power comes in via the switch or the lights will determine what to use. Basically the Ceiling Box in the diagram is your junction box and the Light in the circuit is all of your LED's you are running from that Junction box. Remember you can't just put 10 wires together and wrap them and claim it is acceptable by code. Daisy Chain your bay runs for your LED's (all led's in one bay are connected in parallel) - so you have 1 line feeding each bay (4 lines from the LED bays to the junction box [J-Box]. Those would be wire nutted together with the switch / neutral and ground. See the diagrams below. Depending on how your 3 way switches are wired up - will determine what you need to do and how to make it right and easy on yourself.

First Image is a brief look at what you should have when you are done.

[image: What the Wiring should be similar to.]

This is a 3-Way that depicts the power going through the switches.

[image: 3-Way Neutral through and 2 wire with ground]

[image: 3-Way 2 wire]

There are other ways a 3-way could be wired but I felt that this would be easy enough for you to follow and if you needed to (if yours was wired power through the lights for example)  - you could research and find that.